# Tea offered by bank Halal or Haram?

Tags: quran, hadith

Assalam-o-Alaikum,
I have to visit bank for my business needs. Sometimes,they offer tea or biscuits or other refreshments which I courteously reject. Is it Halal to accept such offerings? Please answer with references from Quran and Sunnah.